# How to include %20 for string search in URL parameter using mongoose

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm kind of new with MEAN stack development and I'm using this https://github.com/diegohaz/rest in my project. I'm trying to filter my mongoose query by slug but it doesn't show result if the string has %20 on it. Example in my database.

```
{name:"fname lname", slug:"fname%20lname"}
```

Then if I search it like this there is no result.

```
domain.com/by_slug/fname%20lname
```

But if I tried to remove %20 in the database like this

```
{name:"fname lname", slug:"fname lname"}
```

Then the result is correct. I think %20 is removed and converted to space during the search process. Sorry I'm from the PHP, MySQL environment.

Here my controller code.

```
    export const showBySlug = ({ params, query }, res, next) =>   
    Staff.find({ 'slug': params.slug })
    .then(notFound(res))
    .then((staff) => staff.map((staff) => staff.view()))
    .then(success(res))
    .catch(next)
```

Comment: *"I think %20 is removed and converted to space during the search process."* - I'm **positive** the actual gathering of `req.params` in express does indeed decode the UrlEncoded string. Fix it with `params.slug.replace(/ /,"%20")` and then this will match what is stored. Or was stored before you changed it.

Comment: Note the [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.params) *"NOTE: Express automatically decodes the values in req.params (using decodeURIComponent)."* Also noting that `req.query` should include the original non-decoded string. But nothing to do with MongoDB or Mongoose, which are both just storing what they are told to.

Comment: Thanks Sir! @NeilLunn it works. Please add it as an answer so I can vote for it. :D

Comment: I'm too lazy to scan the whole documentation because I'm on a tight schedule. Thank you though. :D

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Neil Lunn for his answer.

There seems to be a problem using

```
params.slug.replace(/ /,"%20")
```

because if the slug is 3 word it is throwing some error. So instead of using replace I just encoded it back using encodeURIComponent() since it is automatically decoded by express.

```
Staff.findOne({ 'slug': encodeURIComponent(params.slug) })
    .then(notFound(res))
    .then((staff) => staff ? staff.view() : null)
    .then(success(res))
    .catch(next)
```